# Typetags not working inside of code block scope?

Tags: scala

Ok so the real reason I ran into this is that my ScalaTests failed to compile, because I defined some of the classes inside of the test scope that call another class file expecting to work with TypeTags. Notice that because class B is within my "test" (pretend this is a scala test call) , typetag no longer becomes viable. I suspect maybe I shouldn't be attempting this on an anonymous class inside of a local scope, but could someone help me understand please? Thanks

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.Symbol


class TypeTagger[T:TypeTag] {
  val tt = typeTag[T]
}

object TypeTagger {
  def apply[T]()(implicit  tt:TypeTag[T]) = new TypeTagger[T]
}

object TestRunTypeTagger extends App {
  class A

  val test = new TypeTagger[A]

  {
    class B
    val test2 = TypeTagger[B]()    //fails
  }
}
```

Error:
No TypeTag available for B
    val test2 = TypeTaggerB

> ```
>                        ^ not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit tt:
> ```
>
> reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[B])chorle.scala.testarea.TypeTagger[B]
>   in object TypeTagger. Unspecified value parameter tt.
>       val test2 = TypeTaggerB

```
                         ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work with a `WeakTypeTag` instead of a `TypeTag` (also change `typeTag` to `weakTypeTag`). I have no idea why really; couldn't find any documentation about this specifically.

Comment: Thanks for finding this, I wish I could have discovered more but I'm not really sure what's going on. Do you know if WeakTypeTags have any runtime use or are the designed for Macro manipulation only?